# Net Core - files do not get copied to the referencing project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

Steps to reproduce:

1. In .Net Core 2.0, create a solution with console app project `A` and class library project `L`.
2. Make `A` reference `L`.
3. Add text file `T` to project `L`.
4. Right-click on `T`, select properties, change `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`.
5. Build the solution for the 1st time - `T` gets copied to the output folder of both `A` and `L`.
6. Edit `T` and build again - `T` gets updated in the output of `L`, but NOT `A`.

If after editing `T` you `Rebuild` solution, then `T` gets updated in the output of both projects, but if you just `Build`, it only gets updated in the output of `L`.

Comment: Not sure that's implemented or a bug in the up-to-date check, you could open an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/project-system about it to get a response from the team.

Comment: Thanks @MartinUllrich, just open an issue https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/3637